# Corresponding dictionary key from single list value?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I am looping through a folder, finding the file name, and then trying to associate the file name I found to a value in a dictionary. I will then hopefully take the dictionary value for each file and use it for something else.

When extracting the file name it comes out as a list.

The code below shows exactly what I get. 'fileName' comes out as ['2_data'].

I need to find the corresponding dictionary value to this list value. "data2"

how would I go about this?

```
# dict
csvdict = ({"1_Data" : "data1",
            "_2_data" : "data2",})
# example name
nameData = 'C:/folder/1/2\3\3\CSV Files\\2_data.csv'


csvName = (re.findall('CSV Files[^\w]+([\w\d\s-]+)', nameData))

print(csvName)
```

when I try this code I get an `TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'` error. I do not know how to convert the list value to something the dictionary will read.

```
if csvName in csvdict:
    print(csvdict[csvName])
```

---

Error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-71-86fc5d1ebca7> in <module>()
     22 #csvdict[fileName]
     23 #DICTIONARY ATTMEPT**********************************************************
---> 24 if csvName in csvdict:
     25     print(csvdict[csvName])
     26 

TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

Comment: Can you update your question the the full error trace please?  This will make debugging easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use a list as a dictionary key (because they're unhashable as the error message states).

The following avoids the issue:

```
if csvName[0] in csvdict:
    print(csvdict[csvName[0]])
```